# Is it possible to change a Proxy's target?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, ecmascript-6

I have a class that implements the XMLHttpRequest interface. Depending on the URL passed to `open()`, I can determine whether to use the default XMLHttpRequest or my custom implementation. My idea is to use a proxy to do this:

```
let xhr = new XHRProxy();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://blah'); // Decide here depending on URL
```

I did some tests using the ES6 Proxy, which seems promising, but unfortunately the proxy target cannot be modified after constructing the Proxy:

```
var foo = {
    name() {
        return "foo";
    }
};
var bar = {
    name() {
        return "bar";
    }
}
var handler = {
    get(target, property, receiver) {
        if (property === "switchToBar") {
            // FIXME: This doesn't work because a Proxy's target is not exposed AFAIK
            receiver.target = bar;
            return function() {};
        } else {
            return target[property];
        }
    }
}
var proxy = new Proxy(foo, handler);
console.log(proxy.name()); // foo
proxy.switchToBar();
console.log(proxy.name()); // foo  :(
```

I think I can accomplish what I want by not setting a target at all - instead defining all traps to delegate to the desired object - but I'm hoping for a simpler solution.

Comment: Notice that you are (trying to) change the target already on getting the `.switchToBar` property, not on calling the `.switchToBar()` method

Comment: Yeah, but I don't think it matters for this example. And to use it with XHR.open, I actually do want to set the delegate before calling the XHR.open implementation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's a go at "defining all traps to delegate to desired object"

```js
(function () {
  let mutableTarget;
  let mutableHandler;

  function setTarget(target) {
    if (!(target instanceof Object)) {
      throw new Error(`Target "${target}" is not an object`);
    }
    mutableTarget = target;
  }

  function setHandler(handler) {
    Object.keys(handler).forEach(key => {
      const value = handler[key];

      if (typeof value !== 'function') {
        throw new Error(`Trap "${key}: ${value}" is not a function`);
      }

      if (!Reflect[key]) {
        throw new Error(`Trap "${key}: ${value}" is not a valid trap`);
      }
    });
    mutableHandler = handler;
  }

  function mutableProxyFactory() {
    setTarget(() => {});
    setHandler(Reflect);

    // Dynamically forward all the traps to the associated methods on the mutable handler
    const handler = new Proxy({}, {
      get(target, property) {
        return (...args) => mutableHandler[property].apply(null, [mutableTarget, ...args.slice(1)]);
      }
    });

    return {
      setTarget,
      setHandler,
      getTarget() {
        return mutableTarget;
      },
      getHandler() {
        return mutableHandler;
      },
      proxy: new Proxy(mutableTarget, handler)
    };
  }

  window.mutableProxyFactory = mutableProxyFactory;
})();

const { 
  proxy, 
  setTarget 
} = mutableProxyFactory();

setTarget(() => 0);
console.log(`returns: ${proxy()}`);

setTarget({ val: 1 });
console.log(`val is: ${proxy.val}`);

setTarget({ val: 2 });
console.log(`val is: ${proxy.val}`);

setTarget(() => 3);
console.log(`returns: ${proxy()}`);
```

I feel like there must be some reason this isn't supported out of the box, but I don't have enough information to comment on that further.

After hacking on this for a while, I've observed a few things. It seems the original target that the proxy constructor is called with is treated as part of the proxy's identity regardless. Setting the original target to a plain object and swapping the target to a function later raises an error, when the proxy is called. There are definitely some rough edges to this, so use with caution.

Comment: Oh very clever! Nice idea to use a proxy for the handler, which allows the target (and handler) to be changed, with very minimal code. You're right that there are some issues with this kind of hack. I ran into a few testing my (less elegant) implementation. For example, `Object.preventExtensions(proxy);` will throw an error because Proxy performs some validation using the target it was constructed with instead of the mutable target. I think not having setters for targets/handlers is an oversight - and even if there are good reasons, it's still sad. This mostly works at least. Thanks!

Comment: Nice stuff! Check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54460544/2482744) based on this and maybe consider editing your answer based on it since yours is at the top.

Answer (score 8):

I took John's answer and improved it (I hope):

```
const mutableProxyFactory = (mutableTarget, mutableHandler = Reflect) => ({
  setTarget(target) {
    new Proxy(target, {});  // test target validity
    mutableTarget = target;
  },
  setHandler(handler) {
    new Proxy({}, handler);  // test handler validity
    Object.keys(handler).forEach(key => {
      const value = handler[key];
      if (Reflect[key] && typeof value !== 'function') {
        throw new Error(`Trap "${key}: ${value}" is not a function`);
      }
    });
    mutableHandler = handler;
  },
  getTarget() {
    return mutableTarget;
  },
  getHandler() {
    return mutableHandler;
  },
  proxy: new Proxy(
    mutableTarget,
    new Proxy({}, {
      // Dynamically forward all the traps to the associated methods on the mutable handler
      get(target, property) {
        return (_target, ...args) => mutableHandler[property].apply(mutableHandler, [mutableTarget, ...args]);
      }
    }),
  )
});
```

Some important differences:

1. John's version only has one `mutableTarget/Handler` variable shared by all results from `mutableProxyFactory`, so you probably can't call it multiple times.
2. The handler is allowed to have additional keys, because there's no reason it shouldn't.
3. Traps in the handler have `this` bound to the handler, as in a normal `Proxy`.
4. The user can give initial values for the handler and target. A value for the target is actually required.
5. `mutableProxyFactory` isn't assigned globally to `window`.

EDIT: here's a similar version but implemented as a TypeScript class. Haven't tested this one.

```
class MutableProxy<T extends object> {
  constructor(private _target: T, private _handler: ProxyHandler<T>) {
    this.target = _target;
    this.handler = _handler;
  }

  public get target() {
    return this._target;
  }

  public set target(target: T) {
    new Proxy(target, {});  // test target validity
    this._target = target;
  }

  public get handler() {
    return this._handler;
  }

  public set handler(handler: ProxyHandler<T>) {
    new Proxy({}, handler);  // test handler validity
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(handler)) {
      if (Reflect.has(Reflect, key) && typeof value !== 'function') {
        throw new Error(`Trap "${key}: ${value}" is not a function`);
      }
    }
    this._handler = handler;
  }

  public get proxy() {
    return new Proxy(
      this.target,
      new Proxy({}, {
        // Dynamically forward all the traps to the associated methods on the mutable handler
        get(target, property) {
          return (_target: T, ...args: any[]) => {
            const {handler} = this;
            return handler[property].apply(handler, [this.target, ...args]);
          };
        }
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand how this would be used and it's not making sense to me. I have a situation where I want to "reload" an object and still have the existing references to the object work much like the initial question. Can you please add a usage example to your code?

Comment: @Ravenex it's similar to John's answer, write `const { 
  proxy, 
  setTarget 
} = mutableProxyFactory(initialTarget);` then have everything refer to `proxy` and use `setTarget` to reload to a new value.

Answer (score 6):

> Is it possible to change a Proxy's target?

No, this is not possible. The proxy handler is a quite generic interface already, and by defining all traps to forward the operation to a different handler this is easily achievable. That's why there is no extra method to change the target, the interface is kept minimal. By not making the target changeable, also the shape of the proxy is preserved (e.g. whether it's callable or an array).

Comment: I felt like this was a very negative and unhelpful answer until I read the last sentence (about the shape of the proxy), which explains, why they could not provide the requested functionality. Perhaps you could make this aspect stand out a bit more.

Answer (score 4):

How about this?  Instead of making `foo` or `bar` the target directly, we use a box for our target, and put `foo` or `bar` into the box.

```
var foo = {
    name() {
        return "foo";
    }
};
var bar = {
    name() {
        return "bar";
    }
};
var handler = {
    get(target, property, receiver) {
        if (property === "switchToBar") {
            target.content = bar;
            return function() {};
        } else {
            return target.content[property];
        }
    }
};

var box = {content: foo};
var proxy = new Proxy(box, handler);

console.log(proxy.name()); // foo
// Switch over to bar by calling the function
proxy.switchToBar();
// Or, we could do the switch from out here
box.content = bar;
// Either way, we get the same result
console.log(proxy.name()); // bar
```

In this case, our box is an object with property `content`.  But alternatively, you could use an array with an item at index 0.

Comment: I love how simple and easy this is! Great thinking @joeytwiddle

Comment: Note that when calling methods (e.g. `proxy.name()`), `this` will be the Proxy instance inside the method, which may have unexpected consequences.