# Can Array.isArray be tricked?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I understand the concept of prototypes very well; so when I tried this, I was confused at first:

```
var obj = {};
Object.setPrototypeOf(obj, Array.prototype);
console.log(Array.isArray(obj)); // false?
```

Even scarier:

```
var arr = [];
Object.setPrototypeOf(arr, Object.prototype);
console.log(Array.isArray(arr)); // true?? 8-{
```

Until I did my research and found that `Array.isArray` looks for a [hidden property of the object: [[DefineOwnProperty]]](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ordinary-and-exotic-objects-behaviours.html#sec-array-exotic-objects).

Is this something that is completely immutable on an existing object? Or could a plain object `{}` be mutated such that calling `Array.isArray` on it would return `true`?

Comment: [Can you fake out Array.isArray() with a user-defined object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672038/can-you-fake-out-array-isarray-with-a-user-defined-object)

Comment: According to the spec IIRC arrays are a type of 'exotic object' and Array.isArray checks not only that the argument inherits from Array.prototype but is also one of those exotic objects. AFAIK using the class inheritance syntax *does* work correctly but prior to es6 there is no way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `Array.isArray` cannot be tricked.

And there's no way to change an object between an array and non-array. Just like you [cannot change the callability of a function object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29798915/1048572), not even through [the target of a proxy object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39552012/1048572).